# boost::signals::scoped_connection doesn't work in std::vector. why?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

As I understand it, `scoped_connection`s are meant to automatically disconnect when they go out of scope, and not before. I've found that this doesn't work correctly when the scoped_connection is in `std::vector` (and it probably fails for other containers as well).

eg.

```
using boost::signals::scoped_connection; // just for readability
boost::signal<void ()> sig;
std::vector<scoped_connection> connection_vec;

connection_vec.push_back(sig.connect(foo));
assert(connection_vec.back().connected()); // this assertion fails!
```

I've seen this explained by claiming that `std::vector` requires that the elements be copyable whereas `scoped_connection` is uncopyable - but that's not entirely true. `std::vector` only requires that the elements be *moveable*. (And I expect `scoped_connection` should be moveable.)

For example, the following code works:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<scoped_connection>> vec2;
// Note that std::unique_ptr is uncopyable, but moveable

vec2.push_back(std::unique_ptr<scoped_connection>(new scoped_connection(sig.connect(foo))));
assert((*vec2.back()).connected()); // this assertion succeeds!
```

Besides, if the problem was due to `std::vector` trying to copy an uncopyable thing, then shouldn't that produce a compiling error?

So I'm wondering what is the actual reason for `scoped_connection` not working correctly inside a `vector`, and is this a problem that can be fixed within boost.

(I tested this on gcc version 4.8.0 with boost version 1.53.0.)

Comment: Is this C++11? Or not? What flags are you passing to `gcc`?

Comment: It is C++11. `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -DDEBUG -O0 -g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[scoped_connection](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html) has no move constructor (yet). So it is not movable as you assume, instead `std::move` will fallback to copy. And as you mentioned you cannot copy around a `scoped_connection`.

Comment: Do you think it's fair to say that a future version of boost should include a move constructor for scoped_connection, and strictly enforce the no-copying rule by deleting the copy_constructor?

Comment: karadoc: Yes, that would make sense. You could actually do that yourself and build your own boost version.

Comment: This has been fixed already since [Boost 1.56](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_56_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html) (notice the move constructor and move assignment operator).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `emplace_back`, `push_back` copies.

Comment: That doesn't rly change the problem. Since `emplace_back` can cause existing elements to be copied around when re-allocating memory.